# Keep getting autodeply.zip missing for ubuntu touch

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

I'm trying to follow the instructions on the ubuntu wiki but everytime I run the `phablet` flash command I get :

```
can't open cache/recover/ubuntu_command
checking for autodeply.zip
autodeploy.zip not found
```

I am trying to install on a nexus 4 4.4 system, does anyone what might be wrong?

Comment: Which wiki are you following? eg. what URL ?

Comment: I used this: http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/install  and I ran it off of a virtual machine of ubuntu

Comment: I will re-test full install on my **Nexus 4**, and report back.

Comment: I think the recent build (from a week ago) does a rapid battery drain, even when the device appears off. *Plug into AC powered USB cable, fully charge, and re-install ..* (will keep you posted)

Comment: ***QUESTION:*** What version of Android (eg. **4.2** JB or **4.4** Kitkat) did you start from?

Comment: I started from 4.4.2

Comment: I've been testing my Nexus-4, with **4.4.2** (KitKat), and NO issues with battery. I will try to install **Ubuntu Touch** again shortly. *Try again yourself, but starting from **4.2**.*

Comment: I'll try later this week and report back to this thread, bogged down with finals for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First download the hardware specific one at here : http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/current/

Then install adb drivers with fastboot tool

```
adb reboot fastboot
fastboot flash recovery saucy-preinstalled-recovery-armel+grouper.img
fastboot flash boot saucy-preinstalled-boot-armhf+grouper.img
fastboot flash system saucy-preinstalled-system-armel+grouper.img
```

Then boot your phablet into recovery mode

```
adb reboot recovery
```

make a directory as

```
/sdcard/autodeploy.zip
```

Then send that downloaded zip into /sdcard/autodeploy.zip.

EX:`adb push /path/to/your/downloaded/saucy-preinstalled-touch-armel+grouper.zip /sdcard/autodeploy.zip`

again reboot into recovery mode

```
adb reboot recovery
```

and gain create the above autodeploy directory in the same way and then

```
adb push /path/to/your/downloaded/saucy-preinstalled-touch-armhf.zip /sdcard/autodeploy.zip
```

Then reboot the device

```
adb reboot recovery
```

[To know more about your issue you must go through these steps.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install#ManualDownload&Installation)

Comment: It worked until I started booting up the device, the screen just stayed black and randomly when I reboot it, it said it was in download mode even though there was no way it could download anything